# Default or custom domain name address between web apps in CloudBees run@cloud

Tags: cloudbees

I have multiple web applications running in CloudBees run@cloud. I need to communicate between these applications using HTTP. I have SSL router and custom domain names configured for all these apps too. Should I use the custom domain names or the default xxx.cloudbees.net address in the communication?

I understand that using SSL gives me better security, but I'm thinking more in the lines of performance, flexibility and data transfer costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom domain name will only "consume" a DNS lookup to resolve the the adequate cloudbees.net node. I don't think one or the other name will have any significant impact on performances and network costs as the IP address has been resolved to internal routes.